# How to inject mocked restTemplate in moked service with @WebMvcTest spring test

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, mockmvc

I'm trying using `@WebMvcTest` and mock my service with `@MockBean` injecting `restTemplate` var to be mocked ( `junit5`).

How to use a bean configuration in service mocked and how to mock restTemplate var inside service mocked?
I need to qualifier `restTemplate` from service with configuration has already created.

Bean Configuration class

```java
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfig {
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(){
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

Service class

```java
@Service
public class MyService {

    // restTemplate is coming null on tests
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public ResponseEntity<Object> useRestTemplate() {
       
            return restTemplate.exchange(
                        "url", 
                        HttpMethod.POST,
                        new HttpEntity<>("..."), 
                        Object.class);
         
    }
}
```

Test class

```java
@WebMvcTest(controllers = MyController.class)
class MyControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private MyService myService;

    @MockBean
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;


    @Test
    void test() throws Exception{
    
        when(gatewayRestService.useRestTemplate()).thenCallRealMethod();
    
        when(
             restTemplate.exchange(
                 anySring(),
                 eq(HttpMethod.POST),
                 any(HttpEntity.class),
                 eq(Object.class)
             )
        ).thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok().body("..."));
    
        mockMvc.perform(
                    post("/path")
                    .content("...")
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                )
                .andExpect(status().isOk() );
    }
}
```

I have tried using `@Import(RestTemplateConfig.class)` on `MyControllerTest` but no success, restTemplate keep going null on tests in service

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to mock `RestTemplate`? `@WebMvcTest` is used to create a Spring MVC test that focuses only on Spring MVC components, meaning your `MyController` only. You should only bother mocking `RestTemplate` if you want to unit test `MyService`, which is not the case.

Having said that, you only need to mock `MyService` as follows:

```java
@WebMvcTest(controllers = MyController.class)
class MyControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private MyService myService;

    @Test
    void test() throws Exception {
        when(myService.useRestTemplate()).thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok().body("..."));
    
        mockMvc.perform(
                    post("/path")
                    .content("...")
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                )
                .andExpect(status().isOk() );
    }
}
```